# Why does the reference have a size in the memory even if it doesn't refer to an object in this code example?

Tags: java, oop

Here in class animal getObjectSize on variable 'name' return 0

```java
class Animal {

    String name;

    public Animal() {
        System.out.println(ObjectSizeCalculator.getObjectSize(this.name));
    }
}
```

Here in class Dog getObjectSize on variable 'dogName' return 0

```java
class Dog extends Animal{
    String dogName;

    public Dog() {
       System.out.println(ObjectSizeCalculator.getObjectSize(this.dogName));
    }

    public void dogplay(){
        System.out.println("dog playing");
    }
}
```

Here in class Main getObjectSize on Animal object return 16, but getObjectSize on Dog object return 24, but I thought it should return 16 just like animal object

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Animal a = new Animal();
        Dog dog = new Dog();

        long objectSize = ObjectSizeCalculator.getObjectSize(a);
        long objectSize1 = ObjectSizeCalculator.getObjectSize(dog);

        System.out.println(objectSize+" "+objectSize1);

    }
}
```

What I think of is dogName reference size in memory equal 0, and name reference size in Animal class also equal 0, so why after creating a new object of Dog it has a larger size than animal object size?

When I remove (String dogName) from class dog, now Dog object size becomes equal to animal object size.

Comment: What is a `ObjectSizeCalculator`?

Comment: @user7 it's a class that has a method called getObjectSize which returns the size of an object in the memory.

Comment: I can see that. How can we answer without knowing what it is doing and how it is calculating the size? Was it something you wrote or present in a 3rd party library?

Comment: From a quick search, seems it is part of Nashorn

Comment: It is likely that it's from the package [`jdk.nashorn.internal.ir.debug`](https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_nashorn/blob/master/src/jdk/nashorn/internal/ir/debug/ObjectSizeCalculator.java).

Comment: @user7 no I didn't  write it or implemented it, it already exists in jdk

Comment: An object of type `Animal` has a field `name`, while an object of type `Dog` has a field `name` (inherited from `Animal`) and a field `dogName`, so obviously the size of an instance of `Dog` will be larger than an instance of `Animal`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes but the size of the two references equal zero in the memory, actually if you deleted  field 'name' from class Animal the object will have the same size 16, which means the reference has no size in the memory.

Comment: It doesn't, references are 8 bytes (assuming 64-bit without compressed pointers). The problem seems to be that you're trying to infer things from the result for `String` fields pointing to null (null has size 0), and incorrectly assuming that because null is zero, that an object with 1 field and an object with 2 fields would suddenly be the same in size. It is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using an incorrect assumption. The use of

```
System.out.println(ObjectSizeCalculator.getObjectSize(this.name));
```

in your constructor does not get the size of the reference `this.name`, instead it gets the size of the object referred to by `this.name`. Given in your code, `this.name` is `null`, the returned size is `0`.

Given instances of `Animal` have 1 field (`name`), and instances of `Dog` have two fields (`name`, inherited from `Animal`, and `dogName`), instances of `Dog` will obviously need to be larger than instances of `Animal`.

Comment: If what you're saying is right, now if I deleted the field 'name' from class Animal, and then created an object from class Animal it should give me a value less than 16, but I tried it and it gave me 16 as well

Comment: @peterEstifanos Not necessarily, there are some complications with calculating an object size, like padding and rounding that is applied. However, on my machine, when I run the code, I get size 24/32 (with `name` in `Animal`) and 16/24 (without `name` in `Animal`). It would probably be easier to see a the difference by adding a second field to `Animal`.